# verilog - altera fpga "error pin x has multiple drivers due to the non-tri-state driver"

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga, tri-state, nios-ii

I have a 32 bit parellel IO interface (PIO) defined in a NIOS II soft processor. It is for a 32 pin connector on a board.

I instantiate the NIOS in a top level verilog module called `test` below.

On the connector pins 0:4 are JTAG pins and 5:31 are bi-directional pins that I want to be able to set direction and state.

The FT_ADB0-4 pins go to a FDTI chip for the jtag.

My question is how can I correctly write verilog for this.

I want all 32 bins on `CON_0` to be available to the 32 bit PIO in the NIOS. So that when I set for example bit 10 in the PIO I am indeed controlling pin 10 on the connector.

In the code below I get the error

`Error (13076): The pin "CON_0[0]" has multiple drivers due to the non-tri-state driver "FT_ADB1"`

```
module test2 (  CLOCK_50B, CON_0, FT_ADB0, FT_ADB1, FT_ADB2, FT_ADB3, FT_ADB4);

// Basic clocks
input  CLOCK_50B;

// CON_0 parallel ports
inout  [31:0]  CON_0;

// FT2332.. used for JTAG !
input  FT_ADB0; //TCK
input  FT_ADB1; //TDI
output FT_ADB2; //TDO
input  FT_ADB3; //TMS
input  FT_ADB4; //NRESET 

assign CON_0[2] = (1) ? FT_ADB0 : 'bz; //TCK
assign CON_0[0] = (1) ? FT_ADB1 : 'bz; //TDI
assign FT_ADB2 = CON_0[1]; //TDO output from DUT drives FTDI
assign CON_0[3] = (1) ? FT_ADB3 : 'bz; //TMS

assign CON_0[4] = 'bz;


// Instantiate the Nios II system module generated by the Qsys tool:

    nios2 u0 (
        .clk_clk       (CLOCK_50B),       //  clk.clk
        .CON_0_export   (CON_0)            //  CON_0.in_port

    );

endmodule
```

Comment: What is your question? The error is fairly clear, you have two different things driving the same wire. That's not valid. To fix it create an internal signal for the nios2 instance to use and then in your assign statements specify how to combine the signals.

Comment: @Andrew I'm sorry could you perhaps show me as I don't genuinely don't know how to do it

Comment: @Andrew , the conditional operator is hard coded as always on (`(1)`). Therefore `CON_0[0] = (1) ? FT_ADB1 : 'bz` is equivalent and optimized to `CON_0[0] = FT_ADB1`. `nios2` is also driving this pin at the same time. At most only one should be driving at any given time, all other drivers need to be applying `'bz`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an internal signal CON_0_nios which maps to the NIOS port and is driven by CON_0 whereas it only drives CON_0 bits 5 to 31 with CON_0 bits 0 to 4 driven by FTDI pins as desired.

This is one way of doing it:

```
module test2 (  CLOCK_50B, CON_0, FT_ADB0, FT_ADB1, FT_ADB2, FT_ADB3, FT_ADB4);

// Basic clocks
input  CLOCK_50B;

// CON_0 parallel ports
inout  [31:0]  CON_0;

// FT2332.. used for JTAG !
input  FT_ADB0; //TCK
input  FT_ADB1; //TDI
output FT_ADB2; //TDO
input  FT_ADB3; //TMS
input  FT_ADB4; //NRESET 

// NIOS mapping signal
wire   [31:0]   CON_0_nios; 

//CON_0 FTDI Assignments
assign CON_0[2] = (1) ? FT_ADB0 : 1'bz; //TCK
assign CON_0[0] = (1) ? FT_ADB1 : 1'bz; //TDI
assign FT_ADB2 = CON_0[1]; //TDO output from DUT drives FTDI
assign CON_0[3] = (1) ? FT_ADB3 : 1'bz; //TMS
assign CON_0[4] = 1'bz;

//CON_0 NIOS Assignments
assign CON_0[31:5] = CON_0_nios[31:5]; 

//CON_0_nios Inputs - not required as covered by port mapping
//assign CON_0_nios[31:0] = CON_0[31:0];

// Instantiate the Nios II system module generated by the Qsys tool:
nios2 u0 (
    .clk_clk       (CLOCK_50B),       //  clk.clk
    .CON_0_export  (CON_0_nios)       //  CON_0.in_port
);
```

Comment: many thanks for taking the time to reply, it make sense when I see it. Am I right in saying that `assign CON_0_nios[31:0] = CON_0[31:0];` is not required. Actually when I include it i get the error `Error (10664): Bidirectional port "CON_0[31]" directly or indirectly feeds itself`. Thanks

Comment: I mean that I can control bits 5:31 just using `assign CON_0[31:5] = CON_0_nios[31:5]; `

Comment: yes @horizon you are right...`assign CON_0_nios[31:0] = CON_0[31:0];`  is covered by the port mapping.. my bad :(. Have commented it out.